# Understanding とは名ばかりの

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 早期引退してこれから自由を謳歌するのだと意気込んでいたが、気がつけば、**散策とは名ばかりの**徘徊や、さして興味のない映画とテレビで時間を潰し、一日を無理矢理終わらせるために酒を喰らう日々。毎日夜が無駄に長い。
>
> リコリス・リコイル Ordinary days

I know the bold part means "a walk in name". But I’d like to know what grammatical function the とは is. I guess the と is quotative と but haven’t seen とは used like that. Should I memorize とは名ばかりの as a fixed expression?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to consider it a fixed pattern, but [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF/#jn-159809) has

> 定義・命題などの主題であることを示す。…というものは。「友情―、かけがえのないものだ」,

so you can consider とは as an emphatic topic marker - *A walk **is** just in name*.

---

One could argue it is not quotative と + contrastive は as in

- とはいうものの
- とはいっても,

where は can be dropped.

In とは名ばかり, it is と that could be dropped (if any).